# How to create a localStorage method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, local-storage

I'm a bit confused about the `localStorage` object.
`localStorage` is an object which obviously means that we can create methods, creating properties and such like an ordinary object.

I'm trying to figure out how can i create a method inside `localStorage`.
This is what I currently have:

```
localStorage = {
firstname: function(){
        //get the firsname from the input and set it as the localstorage firsname
        $("#sublog").bind("click", function(){
        $("input[name='fName']").val();
        });
    },
    lastname: function(){
        //get the lastname from the input and set it as the localStorage lastname
        $("#sublog").bind("click", function(){
        $("input[name='lName']").val();
        });
    }
};
```

My html looks like this:

```
<div id="log">
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName" placeholder="FirstName" />
        <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName" placeholder="LastName" />
        <input type="submit" id="sublog" name="login" value="Login" />
    </form>
```

To make it clear, I simply want to store the client's name to `localStorage.firstname` and `localStorage.lastname` when the client inserts his first and last name to save them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way. The `localStorage` object is not an arbitrary object which you can modify to save values -- rather, you have to use the `getItem` or `setItem` methods to store data.

For example, here is an edited version of your code to do what you want:

```
function bind_handlers () {
    $("#sublog").bind("click", function(){
        var firstname = $("input[name='fName']").val();
        var lastname = $("input[name='lName']").val();

        localStorage.setItem('firstname', firstname);
        localstorage.setItem('lastname', lastname);
    });
}
```

And to retrieve those values later, just call `localStorage.getItem('firstname')` or `localStorage.getItem('lastname')`.

If you want to save a data structure like `{firstname : value, lastname : othervalue}`, you first have to convert it to JSON. An example:

```
function bind_handlers () {
    $("#sublog").bind("click", function(){
        var my_data = {
            firstname: $("input[name='fName']").val(),
            lastname: $("input[name='lName']").val()
        }

        localStorage.setItem('keyname', JSON.stringify(my_data));
    });
}
```

And for retrieval:

```
var my_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('keyname'));
```

Answer (score 4):

`LocalStorage` is meant to store data on the client side, not to be overloaded with methods. You can use it this way :

```
localStorage.foo = "bar";
console.log(localStorage.foo);
>> bar
```

If you need to store an object you have to serialize it into a string.

```
myobject = {
    foo: 'bar'
}
localStorage.myobject = JSON.stringify(myobject);
```

And get it back this way

```
myobject = JSON.parse(localStorage.myobject);
```

Anyway, functions cannot (and should not) be stored that way.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work this way. You'll have to assign a key in the `localStorage` collection for your object, **AND IT CANT BE A FUNCTION**, only objects with values. You'll have to `JSON.stringify` to parse the object and then insert it into localStorage.

For more info, look at [this article](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

To set an object into `localStorage`,

```
//set that to localStorage
localStorage["optArray"] = JSON.stringify(optArray);
```

To get the value from `localStorage`,

```
var store = [undefined, null].indexOf(localStorage["optArray"]) != -1 ? [] : JSON.parse(localStorage["optArray"]);
```

In your situation, your click event must insert it into `localStorage` :

```
 $("#sublog").bind("click", function () {
     //set your names in an object
     var name = {
         "first": $("input[name='fName']").val(),
         "last": $("input[name='lName']").val()
     }
     //parse it as a string and store it in localStorage
     localStorage["name"] = JSON.stringify(name);
     alert("Logged in!");
     //now refresh the page - you must see those values in the text box.
 });
```

Then, when the page refreshes, you must get the value from `localStorage` and set it to the textboxes.

```
//page refresh
//check if value exists in localStorage
 if ([undefined, null].indexOf(localStorage["name"]) == -1) {
     //exists
     var name = JSON.parse(localStorage["name"]);
     $("#fName").val(name["first"]);
     $("#lName").val(name["last"]);
 }
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/hgAHs/

Comment: okay and i cant set a variable like that: var firstname = (input value);   var lastname = (input value) and then set it in the localStorage like that: localStorage = { first: firstname, last: lsatname};  ?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to store functions in localStorage?

You store data in localStorage by key-value-pairs. e.g.

```
localStorage.setItem('key','value');
```

where the key and the value are **strings**.
You can retrieve your data by using by using

```
localStorage.getItem('key');
```

Alternatively you may use

```
localStorage.key = 'something'
```

and

```
var something = localStorage.key;
```